# Tfpdf letters overlapping

Tags: php, fpdf

As in the title. I use tfpdf to generate certificates on page with courses. In my local dev environment it works well, but on server letters overlap in one place

[image]

```
$pdf = new tFPDF('L','pt','A4');
$pdf->AddFont($font,'','OpenSans-Regular.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont($font,'',14);

$pdf->SetTopMargin(20); $pdf->SetLeftMargin(20);
$pdf->SetRightMargin(20);
$pdf->AddPage();

// if(!empty($certificate_image)) {
//  $pdf->Image($certificate_image, 0, 0, 850, 600);
// }


$pdf->SetTextColor($certificate_color[0], $certificate_color[1],$certificate_color[2]);
$pdf->SetFont($font,'',60);
$pdf->SetXY(40,100);
$pdf->Multicell(760,50,$certificate_title,0,'C',0);

$pdf->SetTextColor($certificate_color[0], $certificate_color[1], $certificate_color[2]);
$pdf->SetFont($font,'',40);
$pdf->SetXY(40,205);
$pdf->Multicell(760,50,$username,0,'C',0);

$pdf->SetFont($font,'',17);
$pdf->SetXY(190,290);
$pdf->Multicell(460,24, $certificate_text);

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was fault of font file I used.